# Android - Spinning circle appears in Action Bar

Tags: android, action, android-actionbar, geometry

So I have an action bar I am trying to learn and when I implement it I see this white spinning circle left of my first menu item.  Why is this being shown here?

Source:

```
package com.example.lookingfor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.atcAbout:

        break;
    case R.id.atcContact:

        break;
    case R.id.atcRate:

        break;

    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/atcAbout"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="About"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/atcRate"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Rate this app"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/atcContact"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Contact Us"/>

</menu>
```

Main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lookingfor"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
 >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is a screenshot (I cannot post images here yet)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDqm9.jpg

How can I get rid of this spinning circle before I publish the app?  It is an ugly and annoying distraction to the app itself.

Thanks Y'all!

Comment: I also just attempted to add 'ifRoom|withText' to the menu in place of 'ifRoom' but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out the line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` in your `onCreate()` callback.

Comment: Wow do I feel stupid, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar.  In all seriousness that solved the problem, thank you!